# Open links with data format url(href) in new tab with target=_blank

Tags: javascript, html

We have React component with download pdf button. However backend sometimes returns pdf url and sometime base64 content of pdf itself.
when we press on button we need to open pdf in new window.

For case when url provided the task is pretty simple we just need to add `target="_blank"` for link and everything works as expected. However when href=`data:application/pdf;base64,{base64content}` target="_blank" does not work and file always downloaded instead of opening in new tab.

I have found solution with creating new window and creating iframe in it but this approach looks little bit over complicated.

```
const pdfWindow = window.open("");
pdfWindow?.document.write(
 `<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf.base64}'></iframe>`
)
```

I have two questions:

1. why `target="_blank"` does not work for data URI scheme in my case
2. is it possible to make it without js code only with html
3. also with iframe approach I noticed that there is no easy way how you can specify the name for the document
4. and ctrl+s combination also does not work if you want to save pdf document that is displayed in iframe

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/

Comment: Hey @CBroe, thanks for the article. As I see this page was created in 2017 and it is related to 59 version however in my case I already have 105 version and most of the things described in the article still working in my browser. May be they reverted back this proposal

Comment: Top level navigation to Data URIs _does_ get blocked by current browsers.

Comment: @CBroe, looks like it is blocked in Chrome while available in firefox